# Cambiar tamaño de Imagen o Elemento sólo en Móviles con CSS

Tags: css, responsive

Tengo un plugin instalado en mi sitio que hace salga un popup, en lc pc se ve bien, pero en móviles la foto de perfil de la persona o avatar se ve ovalada, cambia el tamaño.

Me podrían dar una opinión sobre como cambiar el tamaño solo en dispositivos móviles?

Mi sitio web:
https://socialmonkeyagencia.com/

Adjunto capturas de referencia.
Gracias[image: Se ve perfecto en PC][image: Vista Móvil ovalada]

Comment: Con el uso de [CSS y media querys](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/) Que al parecer estás usando en la página o no ??

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no se exactamente cuál código usar ni como emplearlo. Saludos

Comment: emm.. CSS.. y el link tiene los ejemplos. Las media query establecen estilos diferentes segun el tamaño determinado.

Comment: No se mucho de css, lo que busco es que alguien con conocimientos me diga que código podría colocar, no se de media queries, entiendo para que sirven pero no se cómo aplicar el código correcto.

Comment: @Ricardo intenta algo con los enlaces que ya te comparten, por favor además lee [ask] y trata de mejorar tu publicación pues puede acabar cerrada

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar agregar en tu css al final...

```
@media only screen and (max-width:786px) {
 .notificationx-content {
   width: 100%;
 }  
 .notificationx-image {
   height: 70px;
 }
}
```

Si es un tema wordpress puedes optar por agregar el estilo en la sección de tu tema que permita agregar css.